# Issue with b2clogin.com domain. With Mac and IOS it shows user names and passwords from other sites

Tags: ios, azure-ad-b2c, keychain

When you go to this example [Registration site](https://msfteventsb2c.b2clogin.com/msfteventsb2c.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1a_universal_signuporsignin_externalstandardidps/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=8dd11ce3-0b17-4121-b7f9-5dc62b3a2ea7&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmshealthcaresummit.eventcore.com%2Fauth%2Flogin&response_type=id_token&scope=openid&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3DrMrxIrU0uhAg3vhqBjvpdL8Y16gx0xYEH5qtrYOMNUSpMJflNz5JcKq0LUOC9hrxitNBkIrpLe-IP3JIOQnS47XqI0urRYr6F-blZQpGQxORCqrDMByEv1Mf40wrmRXZfnogIP2ZtRTzaaiehH7m7JnnU_E215kJxxTUFsoIu82U5FznBGdklspQXlscX9i5NfMh8bmOxZvhMlAAp9UJecNsaRqEZoxX4oC17gDGP0sQjp8aj2Ce6k0q7nrRELaHVhH3WA&response_mode=form_post&appId=8dd11ce3-0b17-4121-b7f9-5dc62b3a2ea7&extension_event_id=25591&x-client-SKU=ID_NET461&x-client-ver=5.3.0.0) on a Mac or IOS device using Safari, it shows your logins from other sites or apps from the keychain that use the *.b2clogin.com domain as well.

How can we prevent this? This creates a bad user experience. A user could easily use login credentials for another site that is using a *.b2clogin.com domain.  Being able to use our own domain could fix this issue.

[image]

Comment: There may be default keychain access is configured did you try by disabling it. Please refer the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-v2-keychain-objc?tabs=objc)

Comment: The above example is a web page (Microsoft’s), so I don’t see how you can do what is in this  document.   When you go into the keychain it’s stored as “Web Form Password” with name *****.b2clogin.com.    So every username and password stored in the keychain  that has b2clogin.com in it would show up creating a horrible user experience.

Answer (score 1):

It is a known behavior of many browsers to share credentials between subdomains usually because if you log in using one subdomain (login.example.com) and later go to another subdomain (say passwordreset.example.com), the browser provides facility for you to login easily.

The way to address this is to add b2clogin.com to [public suffix list](https://publicsuffix.org/). There is no ETA yet of when that process to list b2clogin.com on public suffix list will finish. After that happens, the browsers will need to roll out changes which is beyond our control, and will happen at their own cadence. My suspicion is that it will be a few months for the whole process to take place.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. We're now two years later and the situation still exists. Your 'few months' were optimistic. Maybe this is not going to happen at all. Disastrous UX.